# why does my functions returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, class, object, static, undefined

I want to get a value from class Check but always get `undefined`.

```
class Check {
 static testget() {
    let tester = 1;
    return tester;
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  const test = new Check();
  console.log(test.testget);
};
```

It should show `1` on console, but I always get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will request you to spent some time on [**Classes: Static methods**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods).

Since the member (*testget*) is *static*, you can not access that with an instance (*test*) of the class, use *class* name. Also specify `()` after function name to invoke the function:

```
console.log(Check.testget());
```